# C++/C: Migration from Make to Cmake (Windows and Linux): Platform specific implementations

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, gnu-make

I'm currently migrating a project of 2 million C++/C code lines from Makefiles to using Cmake. Most things are pretty straight forward, but I can't seem to find the best practice to achieve the following:

Many low level (legacy) components in my kernel library use compiler guards to differentiate between the Linux and Windows implementations in the following form:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
// #include ...
#else
// #include ...
#endif
```

and/or:

```
void lowLevelFunction()
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    // Windows implementation
    return;
#else
    // Linux implementation
    return;
#endif
}
```

Is there a best practice to do this on Cmake or to somehow delegate?

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK moving from a makefile to CMake wont change this type conditional compilation.  It might change how you define the actual symbol in your makefile but I've not used them so I couldn't say.

Comment: I assume there are a lot of these code snippets in the projects. Any adjustments of this would probably result in major efforts and run the risk of introducing bugs. There are some adjustments I'd personally do when creating this code from scratch, but updating this may not be worth it. First of all it would be preferrable to use `_WIN32` instead of `WINDOWS` and additionally imho you should check the presence of the `__linux__` definition and fail the compilation with `#error` to ensure the else part does not get activated for unexpected target platforms.

Comment: Moreover I'd try to create 3 files per header: Header: `foo.hpp` common implementations `foo.cpp` windows specific logic `Windows/foo.cpp` linux specific logic `Linux/foo.cpp` allowing you to add the sources using e.g. `target_sources(tgt PRIVATE ${SRC}.hpp ${SRC}.cpp ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}/${SRC}.cpp)` where `SRC` could be a variable of a `foreach()` or a function parameter.

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way of doing it. Definitely for the future (I didn't write it), I would also otherwise use some polymorphism where possible. But in any case, is there any  pre-process variable that exists already from Cmake that I could substitute by the ones already in place?

Comment: If you don't want to modify source code then add `if(WIN32) add_compile_definitions(WINDOWS) endif()` in a root `CMakeLists.txt`